# Check Box List checked method not working

Tags: c#

I have a checkBox list where i want to get all the selected items and assign the selected text to a string. I don't understand why am getting error

> "Error 1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

```
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxA.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (checkedListBoxA.Items[i].Checked==1)  
            {
                SelectedIt += checkedListBoxA.Items[i].Text + "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the [CheckedListBox.CheckedItems Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) - _"Collection of checked items in this CheckedListBox."_?

Comment: Is there a reason why the Checked is not being recognized.

Comment: Yes, If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.item(v=vs.110).aspx), the return type is `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Foreach**

```
foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{                
     textBox1.Text += itemChecked.ToString() + " ";
}
```

**Or Using For Loop**

```
for(int i = 0; i<checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
     for(int j = 0; j<checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; j++)
     {
          if(checkedListBox1.Items[i] == checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[j])
          {
               textBox1.Text += checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + " ";
          }
     }                
}
```

This both codes will print all the selected items of `checkedListBox1` in `textBox1`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i used foreach but i just don't understand why the above solution did not work. `

```
String SelectedIt = "";


            foreach (int indexChecked in checkedListBoxA.CheckedIndices)
            {


                SelectedIt += checkedListBoxA.Items[indexChecked].ToString() +", ";

            }
```

`